# GlassFish 3.1 Netbeanz 7 and REST web services

Tags: rest, netbeans

I tried to run example here http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipzz.html  and didnt work...  There is a [bug](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=192733) at netbeans site but i couldnt understand what they are talking about.
It seems that wadl file isnt created....
However a workaround for this was to use the servlet       `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer`
and seems to work...
Does anyone knows whats wrong ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer..
The problem was that i did the mistake to use the glassfish version that came with Netbeans.  This doesnt work . Installing glassfish seperately did work greatly.

Answer (score 1):

The RESTful stuff in NetBeans and Glassfish definitely works, I use it on a daily basis.

Try following this [NetBeans tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html) and see if you get anywhere. I've always found the tutorials on the NetBeans site too be very helpful, and easy to follow.